# Getting the status of expo-sharing

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm using expo-sharing to download PDF file. And I'm trying to notify the user about the status of the downloading (such as downloading, cancel, completed). But It is unable to detect the file is downloaded. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

share some code please, maybe you could user awit download().then (response=>{if response=="success" then Toast ('success') else Toast("failed")}
this is a psudo code for the issue

Comment: This is what i would like to do. The problem is I cannot detect the status of the downloading, it doesn't return any finish message while using expo-sharing in IOS. So my question is it able to get any finish message when using expo-sharing in IOS